# common name space in git

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to have a common namespace for refs, especially tags.

Consider the case where I have 3 repos: RepoA, RepoB and RepoC.

I want to have a common name space for tags so that Tag names used in RepoA can be used in RepoB but is not a different object. The Tags names should be able to be pre-defined and can be used in all these repos if already defined.
Also, if a common namespace for files is also possible, then it can prevent creation of same files in different repo's which are part of a project.

I know it is a strange question, but is there some way?

Comment: Are RepoA, RepoB and RepoC related to one another?  For example, are they all cloned from another repo?  Or B and C are clones of A?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is possible to do anything with hooks and scripts I won't say what you want to achieve is impossible, but I don't think it is worth it.

It seems you are looking to enforce what would I would call a shop's standards or conventions.  It is better just to come up with a convention and ask your developers to follow it.  I'm sure they will.

For example if you said to the developers that the tags located at `/global/*` are reserved for system use, don't ever use those tags, they won't.

Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to have a common name space for tags so that Tag names used in
>   RepoA can be used in RepoB but is not a different object.

No way - it's *D*VCS after all.

Single *possible* chance - subtle tricky pre-commit hooks, which can block unwanted tags (don't ask me "How to write it")